# Rejected Suggested Edits

Tags: script

*This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)*

## [Rejected Suggested Edits](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts#rejected-suggested-edits)

- Adds new page `/review/suggested-edits/history/rejected` displaying a list of recently rejected suggested edits
- Adds link to above page via mod links page (`/admin/links`) as well as Suggested Edits tabs

  [image: screenshot]
- has toggle date format (like post timelines) and pagination
- anonymous users are easy to spot because they are unlinked
- click on left arrow toggle to display review summary
- anonymous edits reviews are preloaded so we can detect whether they have spam rejection reasons

  [image: screenshot]

  [image: screenshot]

### License

[MIT](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/LICENCE)

### Download

**[View source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/RejectedSuggestedEdits.user.js) ([Install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/RejectedSuggestedEdits.user.js))**

Userscripts require [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net) to be installed on your browser.

If you are on Android, your browser options are [Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) *(recommended)* or [Dolphin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

### Code

This userscript is part of [SOMU (SO-mod-userscripts)](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts)

[Bug reports](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/issues), Forks, and PRs welcome!

Comment: "anonymous edits reviews are preloaded so we can detect whether they have spam rejection reasons"...so what if they don't? What can we do?

Comment: @FrankerZ mods can cross-reference with other accounts on the same IP and/or escalate to CM?